# Disable image loading from webbrowser control before the documentcompleted event

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control

I want to prevent images in a page from being loaded in the `WebBrowser` control. I want it to happen before the `DocumentCompleted` event occurs. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the [DISPID_AMBIENT_DLCONTROL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa770041(VS.85).aspx) [ambient property](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/d0235b98-e879-455a-82ca-a49596e27dfa) or [change the browser's process's WinInet session](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/226473) to use a programmable proxy.

Comment: Please provide an example of doing this.

Answer (score 8):

Try this code:

```
RegistryKey RegKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main", true);
RegKey.SetValue("Display Inline Images", "no");
```

It changes registry key.

Comment: unconfirmed, I was seeing images still. however I think they were cached. "Control Panel / Internet Options", delete I did.