# How Disable Styles & Images Of webBrowser Control (Windows App) Before Loading?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, styles, webbrowser-control, windows

I Want To Disable `Styles` & `Images` Of webBrowser Control (in a Windows Applications) Before Loading?
mean i do n't want any style or image of a web site inside web browser's control.

> Because Of More Speed

how can i disable them?
is there any property for do that?

thanks in advance

Comment: See here for how to disable images: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048424/disable-image-loading-from-webbrowser-control-in-c-net-before-the-documentcompl

Comment: hi dear Scott, i could n't understand any thing from that link. would you please give us an example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is standard functionality of the bundled WebBrowser control.
[This previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048424/disable-image-loading-from-webbrowser-control-in-c-net-before-the-documentcompl) about disabling images in a WebBrowser control suggests using this replacement WebBrowser control which provides the image disabling features you require.

[This site](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18935/The-most-complete-C-Webbrowser-wrapper-control) provides the source code and a demo application. A comment on that site by ATS++ (Titled: Re:HOWTO Encorporate this into my own project.) shows how to use as a standalone WebBrowser control replacement.

But I haven't used it personally, so I am unable to provide any further details on it's workings.

Comment: is there any way without using a replacement control? i want to use regular control! also what about styles?

Comment: I don't think there is any way using the standard control.